# Can someone tell me the use of defaultDestinationName property in JmsTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jms

What is  the significance of the `defaultDestinationName` property in `JmsTemplate`? Even if the value of this field is `null` am I able to send messages.

Comment: That is the destination being used if you use the send methods without an actual destination. Hence the name `defaultDestinationName`...

Answer (score 0):

You can send message without defaultDestinationName (actually there is no such property in jmstemplate).
In this case you should specify the destination in the convertAndSend() or send() methods.